# ESLint complains my code format I don't understand why

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

My react native code is like this:

[image]

When I save, I always get ESLint complaining :

[image]

Is it something about the tab character? Should I do some settings for the Visual Studio Code? I can't figure out how to get rid of this error. Could someone please give a suggestion?

My Visual Studio Code used to be able to auto-format my code when save. Now it completely not working when saving.

**==== UPDATE ====**

I tried also manually format the code:

[image]

But I get the ESLint error:
[image]

Is it some settings of tab key should be modified in Visual Studio Code settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe those characters are newlines. Try this:

- remove the extra newline character after your imports
- put each JSX tag on its on line. Something like this:

```js
return (
  <View>
    <Text>Hello</Text>
  </View>
);
```

[The documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) explains how to set up eslint to automatically fix problems with your code. In Visual Studio Code, open `File > Preferences > Settings` and search for "code actions on save". Click `Edit in settings.json` and enable auto-fixing:

```json
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.fixAll.eslint": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't solve my problem completely, if I write new code, the same complain will come. My Visual Studio Code used to automatically format my code when save, now it would need my manual formatting as your suggestion. I hope someone could explain to me how to get rid of this by change some settings of my Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Please see my update, even I did what you suggested manually, still, it complains the same thing.

Comment: That's *not* the code I suggested. You need to indent the JSX under `return (`, and put the closing `)` on a new line.

Comment: But anyway, my visual studio code used to do the formatting for me even I code like my code snippet in my question. It suddenly starts complaining, my point is asking how can I get back to it used to be.

Comment: Edited my answer to address the question of auto-fixing problems.

Comment: Yes! Your updated answer solved my problem! Thanks.